# Pass a php variable into another php file

Tags: php, mysql

i have a php file which stores a variable, and i need to create a submit form which passes this variable.

So the code of the current file is:

```
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
    echo "<pre>";
    $checked = implode(',', $_POST['checkbox']);
    echo $checked;
}
```

I have to insert the submit form and on click it goes to another php file, i need to get there the $checked variable.. how can i store this variable?..

Thanks you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The principle of POSTing is that you can send all the data to the next .php page.

```
<?php
    if ($checked == 1) {
        $checked = 'checked="checked"';
    }
    else {
        $checked = '';
    }
?>

<form action="POST" method="target_file.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="variableA" value="Something I want target_file.php to know" />
    <input type="hidden" name="variableB" value="Something else I want target_file.php to know" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="gender" value="male" <?php echo $checked ?>" />
</form>
```

Your target_file.php:

```
echo "Here I am :), variableA: ".$_POST['variableA'];
echo "Here I am :), variableB: ".$_POST['variableB'];
echo "Here I am :), My gender is: ".$_POST['gender'];
```

Also, don't trust on checking your  field values that are send through the $_POST. Check what every value is and if it meets certain criteria before sub-statements may be executed.

Comment: Thanks, so, if i just go and put instead of Variable a the $checked, it would be all ok? I'll test this, thanks :)

Comment: Every field within in the form tag will be parsed. But only when it has a "name" attribute. If "value" is not set while a "name" attribute 'is' set, it just passed an empty string ''.

So if you have these input fields:
name, lastname, phone, age

You will get this $_POST:
Array(
    name => 'Value',
    lastname => 'Value',
    phone => 'Value',
    age => 'Value'
)

Comment: Allendar, thanks, what i need is to give the value a variable... like value = $checked and then print the value.. can i do that?

Comment: Yes. You can trigger a inline PHP tag: **#input type="checkbox" name="checked" checked="#?php echo $checked; ?#" /# (Replace the # with > and <

Comment: Allendar, thanks, please in order not to disturb you (you helped me enough, can you please update your answer to me... to see how it works, because i don't know how to get the variable then..thanks..

Comment: I updated the answer. I hope it's clearer now. If not, it's ok to ask. I'll change the explanation into a full example.